# Open buffer in external application using xdg-open

Tags: buffers, files

I want to open the currently viewed buffer in an external application using "xdg-open". What I tried is:

```
(start-process "" nil "xdg-open" (buffer-file-name))
```

But that only returns `#<process >`.

If I replace `"xdg-open"` with the actual application (in my case it's `xppaut`) everything works. That seems only to happen with programs that I call through the terminal. If I want to open the currently viewed buffer in another editor, everything works with `xdg-open`, i.e. I change the default application for that file extension to `gedit` then.

But at the same time `xdg-open` works when I try to call open a file with `xppaut` through Gnome Files (Nautilus). So I'm not really sure if that is an Emacs issue or xdg one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```cl
(defun counsel-locate-action-extern (x)
  "Use xdg-open shell command on X."
  (call-process shell-file-name nil
                nil nil
                shell-command-switch
                (format "%s %s"
                        (if (eq system-type 'darwin)
                            "open"
                          "xdg-open")
                        (shell-quote-argument x))))
```

The trick is to use `shell-file-name` for the process call.

Comment: It works, amazing, thank you! I see now, so I was using the wrong (default) shell, that makes sense.